# "В ногах правды нет"

Tags: фразеология

Когда предлагают присесть, иногда добавляют: "в ногах правды нет".

Откуда пошло это выражение? Какой его сакральный смысл?

Comment: Выбитая "правда" фактически не является правдой реальной. Поэтому все приведенные версии могут иметь место.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В ногах правды нет

"Садись, чего стоишь, ведь в ногах правды нет", - исстари говорят в русском народе. Слова "правда в ногах" связаны со средневековым судебным русским обычаем, который назывался правеж. Это суд, или, скорее, расправа, при которой должника били по босым ступням и пяткам и заставляли стоять на снегу без сапог и лаптей. От боли и холода наказанные нередко брали на себя вину, даже если не совершали проступка: лишь бы наказание закончилось скорее. В итоге такое наказание не могло выявить всей правды. Так и появилось выражение "в ногах правды нет".
[Отсюда](http://letter.com.ua/phrase/index.php?id=580)
Итак, **версия первая**, которой придерживается большинство языковедов. Дело в том, что, начиная с XV века на протяжении нескольких столетий (века этак до XVIII), должников, не плативших долги, на Руси жестоко наказывали. Их ставили на правёж.

Было такое выражение: ставить на правёж - то есть допрашивать с применением силы, истязая. Правёж - от древнерусского "править" (то есть взыскивать). Слово это как раз и означало наказание за неуплату долгов или займа. Ответчика, если он не заплатил, каждый день приводили утром к приказной избе и били батогами по голым ногам, пока долг не уплачивался или его не брали на поруки. Добивались правды, то есть возврата долга. За каждые сто рублей полагался месяц правёжа. Если должник не мог уплатить долг, его имущество переходило кредитору.

Однако, согласитесь, никакое наказание не заставит вернуть долги тех, у кого долгов нет - кого, например, оговорили. Отсюда вроде бы и поговорка - в ногах правды нет. Но есть и **вторая версия**, которая тоже связана с обычаем правёжа. В ногах правды нет могли сказать, если должник сумел спастись от этого самого правёжа бегством!

Ну и, наконец, **третья версия**, которую приводит Словарь русской фразеологии под редакцией Валерия Мокиенко. Она - крестьянская. Вроде бы помещик, когда обнаруживал какую-нибудь пропажу или потраву полей, собирал крестьян и заставлял их стоять, пока не назовут виновного. То есть не скажут правду! А вы уж сами решите, какая версия вам милее.[А это отсюда](http://www.rg.ru/2009/06/04/koroleva.html)

Answer (score 2):

Я добавлю. 
Приведенное EkaterinaKas... исходно принадлежит Марине Королевой 
http://www.rg.ru/2009/06/04/koroleva.html.

Хотя и многократно "позаимствовано". Соответственно, оценка того, где там большинство языковедов - на её совести. Версии такие, разумеется, существуют, но можно ли их принимать на веру?
Что мне категорически не нравится во всех этих и подобных версиях - так это использование отрицания. Если вдуматься, то согласно любому из этих построений надо бы как раз "в ногах правда есть". Ведь каждый раз получалось, что правду выколачивали как раз из ног.

Сколько-нибудь доказуемой альтернативы у меня нет. Но все-таки до кучи предположу, отчасти развивая версию с бегством, что, как вариант, человеку невиновному незачем убегать от суда. Т.е. смысл поговорки в том, что "правду побегом не доказывают".

ЗЫ Не могу почему-то "навскидку" найти пространные обсуждения на грамоте, а методично долбить совершенно некогда. Но там еще версии были... Может, кто-то натолкнётся.

Answer (score 0):

Побежать все могли от нежелания испытывать боль долго. Верится, что отсюда и пошло. Мучайся ногами за правду или нет, но мучайся.